# Swift supply generic method type parameter when implementing protocol method

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol called ContentService that is intended to expose common functionality for reading data from various REST APIs. Each implementation of ContentService will perform the mechanics required by that particular API.

```
protocol ContentService {     
    func loadNextPage<T>(pageStartId: T) -> [Datum]
    //Other methods...
}
```

Since a given API may have a different way of marking page boundaries of returned data, I want to specify the required type in the implementing class as follows:

```
class ServiceA : ContentService {

    func loadNextPage<Int>(pageStartId: Int) -> [Datum] {
        //Do something with pageStartId typed as an Int
        return posts
    }
}

class ServiceB : ContentService {
    func loadNextPage<NSDate>(pageStartId: NSDate) -> [Datum] {
        //Do something with pageStartId typed as an NSDate
        return posts
    }
}
```

**NOTE** that I'm specifying the type parameter in the definition of my implementing types (ServiceA, ServiceB) because they are specific to that service. My expectation is that any instance of these classes would have a method with signature `loadNextPage(pageStartId: X) -> [Post]` where X is the specific type supplied for T when implementing the method.

In order to load a page of data from the api, I would therefore use something like this:

```
let apiA = ServiceA()
let apiB = ServiceB()

let dataA = apiA.loadNextPage(1234)
let dataB = apiB.loadNextPage(NSDate())
```

While this compiles without errors. You can also compile the following without errors:

```
let dataA = apiA.loadNextPage("Anything works here.")
```

Therefore, ServiceA's loadNextPage() method isn't being restricted to Int parameters. Furthermore, in the method definitions for the loadNextPage() method, although the pageStartId parameter seems to be of the expected type when inspecting it in Xcode, I can't use any operators or methods that would normally be accessible on that type. For example, in ServiceA's implementation I can't do `let newId = pageStartId + 5` even though pageStartId should be an Int.

Two questions:

1) Obviously I'm misunderstanding something about generic methods in Swift and would like to know why this pattern can't be used.

2) If anyone has a clever solution to achieve want I'm trying above, I'd love to know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your protocol

```
protocol ContentService {     
    func loadNextPage<T>(pageStartId: T) -> [Datum]
    //Other methods...
}
```

requires a generic method `loadNextPage`, and

```
func loadNextPage<Int>(pageStartId: Int) -> [Datum] {
    //Do something with pageStartId typed as an Int
    return posts
}
```

is exactly that: A generic method where the placeholder happens to
have the name `Int`. Inside the method, `Int` refers to that placeholder type and *hides* the global Swift type `Int`. An equivalent definition would be

```
func loadNextPage<FOO>(pageStartId: FOO) -> [Datum] {
    //Do something with pageStartId typed as an Int
    return posts
}
```

What you probably want is to define a protocol with an *associated type* `T`:

```
protocol ContentService { 
    associatedtype T
    func loadNextPage(pageStartId: T) -> [Datum]
    //Other methods...
}
```

and a class which adopts this protocol with `T == Int`:

```
class ServiceA : ContentService {

    func loadNextPage(pageStartId: Int) -> [Datum] {
        let newId = pageStartId + 5  // <-- This compiles now!
        //Do something with pageStartId typed as an Int
        return posts
    }
}
```

Now

```
let dataA = apiA.loadNextPage(1234)
```

compiles, but

```
let dataA2 = apiA.loadNextPage("Anything works here.")
// error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'
```

doesn't, as expected.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. So this works as stated but when declaring a property of type ContentService in another class I'm now getting the following error: `Protocol 'ContentService' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has associated type requirements`. Although I will be assigning an instance of a concrete class to that var upon initialization, I would like my property declaration to be of the protocol type so that it can reference any of my ContentService classes.

Comment: @Dragonspell: If I remember correctly, that is a known restriction of Swift  currently, you cannot declare a variable of a protocol type if the protocol has an associated type (you should find some Q&A with respect to that error message). Unfortunately, I do not have the time currently for a more detailed response.